# Scala: How to sum all elements with the same index in a list of lists of different lengths?

Tags: scala-collections

I have a list of lists of ints. Need to get a list of sums of all elements in a column, going right to left, letting it be 0 should a value in a column is absent (a row is shorter than others):

```
            ( 1,  7),
    ( 3,  4,  6,  0),
                  (),
( 9,  1,  6,  7,  2),
                 ...
---------------------
( 9,  4, 10, 14,  9)
```

I wrote it in Java (say, an imperative language):

```java
    int[][] s = {
                 { 1, 7 },
           { 3, 4, 6, 0 },
                       {},
        { 9, 1, 6, 7, 2 }
    };
    
    int maxLen = 0;
    for (int[] x : s) {
      maxLen = Integer.max(maxLen, x.length);
    }
    
    int[] sum = new int[maxLen];
    for (int j = maxLen; j-- > 0; ) {
      for (int[] i : s) {
        int idxFromEnd = j - maxLen + i.length;
        sum[j] += idxFromEnd >= 0 ? i[idxFromEnd] : 0;
      }
    }
```

and translated into Scala then:

```scala
  val s = List(
             List( 1, 7 ),
       List( 3, 4, 6, 0 ),
                   List(),
    List( 9, 1, 6, 7, 2 ),
  )

  val maxLen = s.view.map(_.length).max
  val sum =
    for (i <- 0 until maxLen)
    yield s.view.map(row => {
      val idxFromEnd = i - maxLen + row.length
      row.lift(idxFromEnd).getOrElse(0)
    }).sum
```

Gould you guys please suggest an idiomatic way to write it in Scala. Tail recursion is acceptable also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` and `flatMap`:

```scala
val s = List(
             List( 1, 7 ),
             List( 3, 4, 6, 0 ),
             List(),
             List( 9, 1, 6, 7, 2 ),
            )

s.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex).groupBy{case (num, idx) => idx}
 .map{case (k, v) => v.map(_._1).sum}.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

The zipAll is useful for lists of different lengths, so something like this could work:

```
s.reduce((a,b) => //-- combining elements of s...
  a.reverse //-- work from right to left
    .zipAll(b.reverse,0,0) //-- join at the hip - right to left
    .map ( i => i._1 + i._2 ) //-- adding the corresponding elements
).reverse //-- display in left to right order
```